# Standalone Blazor WebAssembly authentication very slow

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, blazor, webassembly

Using AddOidcAuthentication and linking to AWS Cognito service resulting in a huge delay between start of the auth process and redirecting to AWS for sign in.  This appears even using a very vanilla Blazor app and add in support for authentication as per Microsoft Docs.  Looking to see if anyone else I experiencing this issue and or workaround/fix?

Json options very simple

```js
  "OidcProviderOptions": {
    "Authority": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-XXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "CLIENT_ID"
  },
```

Auth process initially throws an error due to 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' imposed by Cognito.  There then follows a 10 second delay before it redirects to the login screen - no other requests present during that time.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Yes, I'd looked at that but switching from Cognito isn't desirable (but may end up being the only route).  I've published a version too which shows the same behaviour as he also points out in the question.  I may try Azure B2C to see if this has the same issue.  Will come back, thanks

Comment: Yep, exactly the same with Azure B2C - resolves the slowness in the same way as auth0.  Logged a but with MS around this.  Will link this question to your linked one and add ref to the GitHub issue.

Comment: I've addressed the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70904073/9388563