# integrate blazor with aws cognito using openid

Tags: amazon-cognito, blazor

I am trying to integrate aws cognito in Blazor server app. I have configured user pool in cognito, and changed the startup as

```
services.AddAuthentication()
 .AddCookie()
 .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
  options.ResponseType = "code";
  options.MetadataAddress = "address here";
  options.ClientId = "clientid";
  options.ClientSecret = "secret";
});
```

now how to display the cognito sign in page once the blazor application loads and then after sign in i want to redirect to blazor default page.
any help please.

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61848770/2940908

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor WebAssembly + Amazon Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845477/blazor-webassembly-amazon-cognito)

Comment: @aguafrommars Thanks for those links.. I can progress up to some extent now.
so now on running my app it takes me to the aws cognito page but there i got message as "an error was encountered with the requested page".
and in the url it shows as "error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id="clientid".
any help on this please

Comment: The error says your redirect uri doesn't match with the uri defined in cognito. The redirect uri should be something like https://{yourhost}/singnin-oidc

Comment: @aguafrommars is it necessary to have "signin-oidc" as the redirect url. or i can use any page, like in cognito i have configured as "https://localhost:44370/Logincallback". and in my application there is a page as Logincallback.razor. am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @aguafrommars is it necessary to have "signin-oidc" as the redirect url. or i can use any page, like in cognito i have configured as "https://localhost:44370/Logincallback". and in my application there is a page as Logincallback.razor. am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's not a page, it's the callback path of your authorization handler. You can customize the path with the options `CallBackPath` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.remoteauthenticationoptions.callbackpath?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.CallbackPath);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: A bit confused here. so what exactly the cognito sign in url is. does that path needs to be exist. and with which parameter its comparing and giving the redirect_mismatch error. Please can you guide a bit more

Comment: here is the code in startup.cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
 options.ResponseType = "code";
 options.MetadataAddress = "metaaddress";
 options.ClientId = "clientid";
 options.ClientSecret = "cleintsecret";
 options.CallbackPath = "/https://localhost:44370/Logincallback";

});

and the cognito signin url is : https://localhost:44370/signin-odc

Comment: Update your question, it's redeable in the comment

Comment: the callback path and the redirect uri must match : just don't set the callback path

Comment: i removed the callback setting from code, but still cant get it working.
one thing is there when i launch hosted ui from AWS Cognito it successfully opens the aws signin page, getting error only running from my code.

Comment: the allowed redirect url in cognito must not be a full url with same scheme, host, port and path. You can configure several.

Comment: And you can found in the log witch ones are expected.

Comment: Thanks @aguafrommars. finally it worked, when i tried to search in console log, it seems to be always sending the redirect url as "signin-oidc" irrespective of what i have configured in cognito. so once i configured same in cognito it start working and login page got dispalyed

Answer (score 1):

I spent a couple of days trying to figure this all out.  Following is what I came up with.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
        opt.Authority = builder.Configuration["AWS:Authority"]; //"https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-XXXXX/";
        opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Secret_AWS:ClientId"]; 
        opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Secret_AWS:ClientSecret"]; 
        opt.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        opt.SaveTokens = true;
        opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        opt.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        opt.Scope.Add("openid");
        opt.Scope.Add("email");
        opt.Scope.Add("profile");
        opt.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";  //This is where you can change the callback path.  Just remember to change the ReturnUrl in the Cognito console
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        };
        opt.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents //if you want to see what is going on during the authentication handshake, you can hook into these events as follows (only first one shown for brevity) 
        {
            //order of calling during login.  OnRedirectToIdentityProvider, OnMessageReceived, OnAuthorizationCodeReceived, OnTokenResponseReceived, OnTokenValidated, OnUserInformationReceived, OnTicketReceived, 
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
            {
                AuthEventFlow = $"{AuthEventFlow}OnRedirectToIdentityProvider, ";
            }
        }
   });
string? AuthEventFlow;
```

I found it useful studying the Cognito authentication endpoints [Amazon Cognito Endpoints Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html).  It seems that a lot of the magic happens as a result of setting opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true.  OpenIdConnect then gets all of the various Cognito endpoints by querying https://cognito-idp.Region.amazonaws.com/your user pool ID/.well-known/openid-configuration

In order to call the Cognito hosted UI, create the following Razor pages in your Pages folder

Login.cshtml

```
@page
@model AmmanControls.Pages.LoginModel
@{
}
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace XXXX.Pages
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
        {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri });  
           //This was a critical point for me - it is the entry point to the OpenIdConnect login events
        }
    }
}
```

Logout.cshtml

```
@page
@model AmmanControls.Pages.LogoutModel
@{
}
```

Logout.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace XXX.Pages
{
    public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

You then call these pages as follows:

Shared\LoginDisplay.razor

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name </a>
        <form method="get" action="logout">
            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
        </form>     
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="login?redirectUri=/">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
 </AuthorizeView>
```

Must admit I couldn't believe it when I finally got to click the Login button and all of the redirects just worked!

The problem I'm having now is that @context.User.Identity.Name is null even though the user is authenticated and I'm working out how to get the name of the authenticated user from the claims into the ClaimPrincipal.  Will post an update when I figure that out.