# How do I get the id_token in Blazor WebAssembly after authenticating with OpenId (Cognito)?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, access-token, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've got a .Net Core 3.1 WebApi backend.

I've got a Blazor WebAssembly front-end.

I'm trying to login on the front-end (works) to AWS Cognito (setup as an OpenId provider) and then pass a Bearer token (JWT) to my backend API on each request so that the backend API can access AWS resources using temporary credentials (CognitoAWSCredentials).

I am able to pass a Bearer token on each request from my Blazor front-end to the backend, however the only token I can find to access in Blazor is the Access Token. I need the ID Token in order to allow the backend to generate credentials on my user's behalf.

In my Blazor code I have successfully registered a custom AuthorizationMessageHandler which gets invokes on each HttpClient's SendAsync when accessing my API:

```cs
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpRequestHeaders headers = request?.Headers;
    AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = headers?.Authorization;
    if (headers is object && authHeader is null)
    {
        AccessTokenResult result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
        if (result.TryGetToken(out AccessToken token))
        {
            authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
            request.Headers.Authorization = authHeader;
        }
        logger.LogObjectDebug(request);
    }
    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

This adds the **Access Token** and the backend picks up the token and validates it fine.
However, to create the CognitoAWSCredentials for AWS services to use for privileges, I need the *ID Token*.

**I cannot find any way to access the ID Token within Blazor.**

If I access my backend WebApi directly, it will properly forward me to Cognito to login and then return back. When it does, the HttpContext contains the "id_token". This can then be used to create the CognitoAWSCredentials I need.

The missing link is how to access the ID Token in Blazor so I can put that as the Authorization HTTP header's Bearer token instead of the Access Token.

adding a bit more code context ....

### Program.cs:Main

```cs
string CognitoMetadataAddress = $"{settings.Cognito.Authority?.TrimEnd('/')}/.well-known/openid-configuration";

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
                {
                    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = settings.Cognito.Authority;
                    options.ProviderOptions.MetadataUrl = CognitoMetadataAddress;
                    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = settings.Cognito.ClientId;
                    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = $"{builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress.TrimEnd('/')}/authentication/login-callback";
                    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                })
                .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>()
;

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

string APIBaseUrl = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Deployment")["APIBaseUrl"];
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient(settings.HttpClientName, client => 
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIBaseUrl);
                })
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>()
                ;
```

### Sending the http request (minor changes from the Blazor sample code)...

```cs
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Method = new HttpMethod(method),
    RequestUri = new Uri(uri),
    Content = string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody) ? null : new StringContent(requestBody)
};

foreach (RequestHeader header in requestHeaders)
{
    // StringContent automatically adds its own Content-Type header with default value "text/plain"
    // If the developer is trying to specify a content type explicitly, we need to replace the default value,
    // rather than adding a second Content-Type header.
    if (header.Name.Equals("Content-Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && requestMessage.Content != null)
    {
        requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(header.Value);
        continue;
    }

    if (!requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Name, header.Value))
    {
        requestMessage.Content?.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Name, header.Value);
    }
}

HttpClient Http = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient(Settings.HttpClientName);
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

When the OpenIdConnect middleware tries to authorize with Cognito, it calls:

```
https://<DOMAIN>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT-ID>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44356%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&state=<HIDDEN>&code_challenge=<HIDDEN>&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query
```

*(HIDDEN: inserted by me for some values that might be sensitive)*

- Cognito Docs on /oauth2/authorize: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

*An ID token is only returned if **openid** scope is requested. The access token can be only used against Amazon Cognito User Pools if aws.cognito.signin.user.admin scope is requested.*

Since my normal users are not admins, I'm not requesting the admin scope.

So according to the docs, Cognito should be returning an ID token.
When I print out the claims for the ClaimsPrincipal created by the OIDC middleware in Blazor the token_use is `id`:

```
  {
    "Type": "token_use",
    "Value": "id",
    "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string",
    "Subject": null,
    "Properties": {},
    "OriginalIssuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
    "Issuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY"
  }
```

However the AccessToken added to the Http request is an access_token.
Here's the `token_use` claim from the decoded JWT token added to the HTTP request:

```
  {
    "Type": "token_use",
    "Value": "access",
    "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string",
    "Subject": null,
    "Properties": {},
    "OriginalIssuer": "https://cognito-idp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/<USER-POOL-ID>",
    "Issuer": "https://cognito-idp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/<USER-POOL-ID>"
  }
```

Which *sort of* makes sense since the Blazor API *is* `IAccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken()` ... there just doesn't seem to be an API to request the ID token.

Comment: Your AuthorizationMessageHandler does nothing...Ordinarily you perform an HTTP call, and the AuthorizationMessageHandler automatically and transparently add the access token to the request header, after calling the access token provider, but in your sample code you do that manually... I can't say much with such a meager context you provide: your setting...etc. However, I'd like to direct you to the provider option that has an option named ResponseType which should be set to  "id_token token" in order to get an id_token.

Comment: In order for the token to get on the HTTP request via the HttpClient, there is setup in the Progam.cs:Main - which I have done. I used a custom handler to do logging for debuging mainly and to try and troubleshoot. Cognito requires a response type of 'code' for the OpenId Connect setup - other values fail.

Comment: I have got the same problem, it would be great if someone could help share their experience on how I can access the idToken instead of the accessToken which can be accessed from the IAccessTokenProvider. I do not see any IdTokenProvider

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63109855/3486567 I have not tried it myself yet but seems to be ok @JeffBacon

Comment: Hi @JeffBacon, I have the same setup as you do.  I am able to login fine, but not able to get the access token.   with the following code.
   
        TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();    
         
Because of the “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “DENY“ error.  I have posted a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480229 Can you please help me with it.  Thank you.

Comment: @HExit did you try the code in my answer below? It parses the local storage data in the browser that is saved after a login to get the id_token and access_token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the answers on [How to get the id_token in blazor web assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105618/how-to-get-the-id-token-in-blazor-web-assembly) I was able to get the id_token. Sample code below:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Text.Json
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div>
            <b>CachedAuthSettings</b>
            <pre>
@JsonSerializer.Serialize(authSettings, indented);
            </pre>
            <br/>
            <b>CognitoUser</b><br/>
            <pre>
@JsonSerializer.Serialize(user, indented);
            </pre>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            Everything requires you to <a href="/authentication/login">Log In</a> first.
        </div>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    JsonSerializerOptions indented = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
    CachedAuthSettings authSettings;
    CognitoUser user;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string key = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.CachedAuthSettings";
        string authSettingsRAW = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", key);
        authSettings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CachedAuthSettings>(authSettingsRAW);
        string userRAW = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", authSettings?.OIDCUserKey);
        user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CognitoUser>(userRAW);
    }

    public class CachedAuthSettings
    {
        public string authority { get; set; }
        public string metadataUrl { get; set; }
        public string client_id { get; set; }
        public string[] defaultScopes { get; set; }
        public string redirect_uri { get; set; }
        public string post_logout_redirect_uri { get; set; }
        public string response_type { get; set; }
        public string response_mode { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }

        public string OIDCUserKey => $"oidc.user:{authority}:{client_id}";
    }

    public class CognitoUser
    {
        public string id_token { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public int expires_at { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: However... if you are using the id_token with CognitoAWSCredentials then you will run into this bug (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/pull/1603) which is awaiting merging. Without it, you will not be able to use the AWS SDK Clients directly in Blazor WebAssembly, only pass the id_token to your backend for *it* to be able to create CognitoAWSCredentials.