# How to get the id_token in blazor web assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have got a Blazor WebAssembly (latest 3.2.0) app with oidc Authentication.
The asp.net authentication provides a way to get the accessToken but can't see any means to access the id_token (jwt) which is required for my scenario.
I can see the id_token in the local storage of the browser.
What would be best way to access it?

Thanks

Comment: I guess none of the answers here were useful,  right ? Shall we delete them ?

Answer (score 7):

You can read it from the session storage using JSInterop, it is stored at key *oidc.user:{app baseUri}:{app client id}* :

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
...
@code {
     private async Task<string> ReadIdToken()
     {
          const string clientId = "your oidc client id";
          var userDataKey = $"oidc.user:{NavigationManager.BaseUri}:{clientId}";
          var userData = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<UserData>("sessionStorage.getItem", userDataKey);
          return userData.id_token;          
     }

     class UserData
     {
         public string id_token { get; set; }
         public int expires_at { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work with the latest and .net 5

Comment: @Inaie, actually it does work, I just test it using .Net 5. Are you sure you use an OIDC authentication ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working code sample that allows you to get the id_token in raw format as well as a list of claims parsed from it.

Note: You should authenticate before you can see the results...

```
@page "/"

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@using System.Security.Claims
@using System.Text.Json

<p>@JwtToken</p>

@foreach (var claim in claims)
{
    <p>@claim</p>
}


@code {
      List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
      string JwtToken;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetJwtToken();

    }
    private async Task GetJwtToken()
    {
        var baseUri = NavigationManager.BaseUri.Substring(0, 
                              NavigationManager.BaseUri.Length - 1);
        // client id example: RoleBasedApiAuthorization.Client 
        const string clientID = "<Place here your client id>";
        var key = $"oidc.user:{baseUri}:{clientID}";
        JwtToken = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string> 
                                    ("sessionStorage.getItem", key);

        if (JwtToken != null)
        {
            claims = ParseClaimsFromJwt(JwtToken).ToList();
        }

    }


    public IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);
        return keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));
    }

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys SO much for this - I've been banging my head against this for a week (doh - forgot to look at the browser session data in Chrome to think about using JRRuntime...).

I'm not sure if this is Cognito-specific, but the key for me is not using the NavigationManager BaseUri, but the OIDC Authority.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Text.Json
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div>
            <b>CachedAuthSettings</b>
            <pre>
                @JsonSerializer.Serialize(authSettings, indented);
            </pre>
            <br/>
            <b>CognitoUser</b><br/>
            <pre>
                @JsonSerializer.Serialize(user, indented);
            </pre>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            Everything requires you to <a href="/authentication/login">Log In</a> first.
        </div>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    JsonSerializerOptions indented = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
    CachedAuthSettings authSettings;
    CognitoUser user;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string key = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.CachedAuthSettings";
        string authSettingsRAW = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", key);
        authSettings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CachedAuthSettings>(authSettingsRAW);
        string userRAW = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", authSettings?.OIDCUserKey);
        user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CognitoUser>(userRAW);
    }

    public class CachedAuthSettings
    {
        public string authority { get; set; }
        public string metadataUrl { get; set; }
        public string client_id { get; set; }
        public string[] defaultScopes { get; set; }
        public string redirect_uri { get; set; }
        public string post_logout_redirect_uri { get; set; }
        public string response_type { get; set; }
        public string response_mode { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }

        public string OIDCUserKey => $"oidc.user:{authority}:{client_id}";
    }

    public class CognitoUser
    {
        public string id_token { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public int expires_at { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I get serialization errors if I directly try and convert the string to classes using JSRuntme.InvokeAsync but it works fine with the JsonSerializer, that's why you see that seemingly extra step there.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work with my Blazor 7.0 WASM application that authenticates via OIDC with Google and needs to send the "ID token" to my ASP.NET Web API.  It took me quite awhile to figure out the issue.  As mentioned above, the "access token" is what is getting set in the "Authorization" header by default in the Middleware.  Instead the ASP.NET Web API needs the JWT which is the "ID token".

As mentioned by other responders, this can only be accessed via Javascript.  What I've done in my Blazor app is created a derived class off of AuthorizationHandler like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace ExperiencePlatform.Client.Infrastructure
{
    public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
    {        
        private NavigationManager _navigation;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;
        public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, NavigationManager navigation, IConfiguration configuration, IJSRuntime jsRuntime) : base(provider, navigation)
        {
            _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _navigation = navigation;
            ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { configuration[Constants.ExperiencePlatformServerKey] },
            scopes: new[] { "openid" });     
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            string idToken = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getOidToken", $"oidc.user:{_configuration["Google:Authority"]}:{_configuration["Google:ClientId"]}");
            request.Headers.Add(ExperiencePlatform.Shared.Authentication.Constants.IdTokenHttpHeader, $"Bearer {idToken}");
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }         
    }
}
```

The "getOidToken" function in Javascript looks like this:

```
function getOidToken(key) {
    var strJson = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    if (strJson != null) {
        var json = JSON.parse(strJson);
        return json.id_token;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Remember in your Blazor WASM's Program.cs to set up dependency injection and hook into your CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler class like this:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient(Constants.ExperiencePlatformServerKey, client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config[Constants.ExperiencePlatformServerKey]))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(Constants.ExperiencePlatformServerKey));
```

Finally, on your ASP.NET Web API side, assuming your have a Controller with endpoints defined like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ExperiencesController : ControllerBase {...}
```

In your Program.cs make sure you handle the "OnMessageReceived" JwtBearerEvent and grab the custom Authorization header.  Here's the full code block here:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Google:Authority"];
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Google:Authority"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"],
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                string idTokenHeader = context.Request.Headers[ExperiencePlatform.Shared.Authentication.Constants.IdTokenHttpHeader];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idTokenHeader) && idTokenHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    string token = idTokenHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                    context.Token = token;
                }
                
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }            
        };

    });
```

Followed by the usual suspects of not defining the middleware in the right order:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();   
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```