# Not able to get access token with Blazor WASM with AWS Cognito because X-Frame-Options is set to DENY

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am using Blazor WebWebAssembly as my frontend and AWS Cognito as my IDP.

I can successfully login to AWS Cognito, but not able to get the access token with the following code because of the “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “DENY“ error.

```
 private async Task WriteTokenToConsole()
    {
        var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
        if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token.Value);
        }
    }
```

Yet, if I switch the IDP to Identity Server 4, I can get the access token no problem.

According to this comment https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22651#issuecomment-640565340 , it is because Cognito is not being standard compliant?

Is there a way to work around this?

Thank you

Comment: Except by implementing your `AuthenticationStateProvider` there isn't

Comment: it's stored in the session storage in the browser in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.CachedAuthSettings key. If you use JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", key) you can access the raw JSON and then deserialize it (if you write a custom object matching it's structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to access it via the code on: [How do I get the id_token in Blazor WebAssembly after authenticating with OpenId (Cognito)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063237/how-do-i-get-the-id-token-in-blazor-webassembly-after-authenticating-with-openid?noredirect=1#comment114016274_63063237)

I've since abstracted that into an extension to JSRuntime to make it easier to re-use across my code. But it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Jeff Bacon, It works fine now.
  
It didn't work because I was trying to learn it and did everything from scratch, I was able to login, but no token was stored in Session Storage.  I still don't know why.
    
but, I just tried start with the Blazor WASM template with Individual User Accounts, all I did was just change appsettings.json, once login, all of the tokens (ID, Access and refresh token) are in Session Storage.